# How do I add a WCF Service Reference for my .NET Core App (.NET Framework)

Tags: wcf, web-config, asp.net-core

I'm only using a .net framework with it and I can add a pure c# project that contains the service reference - but I can't create a Service Client with this approach, it tells me it cannot find an endpoint with the proper values

(Contract, Endpoint name, both are identical to the endpoint I copied over to my web.config.)

Is there a specific procedure in which you can add a service reference when it comes to ASP .NET Core? or is it just like regular .NET Framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using HTTP binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access wcf service, If you have control over wcf service implementation side. you can change your service to restful wcf service. if you don't have access to that use seviceutil.exe to get proxy class and config file. 
1. first copy code from proxy class.
2. second add class reference to your ASP.NET code behind.

Check how to use serviceutil.exe on google.
Also go to http://www.wcftutorial.net/ for more details.